# Is there a way to write to PowerShell Verbose stream from C# static (non-PSCmdlet) method

Tags: c#, powershell, static-methods

I have a custom class library that my PowerShell Advanced Functions utilize.  One of the class library features is a static method within a custom class to mimic PowerShell's `Write-Verbose`, called `Utilities.Write.Verbose()`.  It is called within my class library only by other classes and their public methods.  Here is the code snippet of that utility class:

```
namespace Utilities
{

    public class Write
    {

        public static void Verbose(string msg, string source)
        {


            ConsoleColor originalForeGroundColor = Console.ForegroundColor;
            ConsoleColor originalBackGroundColor = Console.BackgroundColor;
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
            Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Black;
            Console.Write("VERBOSE: {0} {1}{2}", source, msg, Environment.NewLine);
            Console.ForegroundColor = originalForeGroundColor;
            Console.BackgroundColor = originalBackGroundColor;

        }

    }

}
```

As you can see, I am writing to just the standard console of whatever the host is.  But, when I need to capture verbose output, the `Console.Write` isn't capture, nor is it directed to PowerShells Verbose stream.

I came across some other sample code on getting access to the RunSpace, but it does not display any verbose output:

```
using (PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create(RunspaceMode.CurrentRunspace))
{

    var _msg = string.Format("VERBOSE: {0} {1}{2}", source, msg, Environment.NewLine);

    VerboseRecord verboseRecord = new System.Management.Automation.VerboseRecord(_msg);

    ps.Streams.Verbose.Add(verboseRecord);

}
```

So, my question is this:  Is there a way to getting the `host` or `PSHost` object from a C# class method, or be able to write string to PowerShell's verbose stream?  My PowerShell module targets Windows Management Framework 4.0, and the Class Library targets .Net 4.6 Framework.

Comment: `but it does not display any verbose output`: just to tick all the boxes, did you run your command with `-Verbose` or set `$VerbosePreference` to ensure you'd be able to see it since it's hidden by default?

Comment: Thanks for asking.  Yes, I have a Cmdlet that takes a `ScriptBlock` as input and then injects `$VerbosePreference = "Continue"` before the commands are run.  Verbose output is shown for those Advanced Functions, but my C# method verbose output isn't shown.